# React day picker gives an error when double click on data

Tags: react-day-picker

> index.js:373 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
> at format (index.js:373:1)
> at AvailableAppointment (AvailableAppointment.js:16:1)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
> at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:20387:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22430:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
> at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:1)
> at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25806:1)

```
import banner from '../../assets/images/chair.png'
import { DayPicker } from 'react-day-picker';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const AppointmentBanner = ({ selected, setSelected }) => {

    let footer = <p>Please pick a day.</p>;
    if (selected) {
        footer = <p>You picked {format(selected, 'PP')}.</p>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="hero min-h-screen ">
                <div class="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row-reverse">
                    <img src={banner} class="max-w-sm rounded-lg shadow-2xl" alt='dental chair' />
                    <div className='border hover:border-primary rounded-lg mx-12'>
                        <DayPicker
                            mode="single"
                            selected={selected}
                            onselected={setSelected}
                            footer={footer} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AppointmentBanner;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

use

```
onDayClick={setSelected}
```

instead of using

```
onselected={setSelected}
```

Answer (score 0):

on v8.1.0 i also got error , i used onDayClick={setSelected} instead of `onselected={setSelected}`

So, You have to use onDayCick instead of onSelected. It will work after clicking twice on a date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use onDayClick = {setSelected} insted of onselected = {setSelected}

```
<DayPicker
dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy"
mode="single"
selected={selected}
onDayClick={setSelected}
/>
```